# Using ENUM to specify User or Admin Session in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

I am currently trying to associate two different sessions from a login process: normal user and privelleged (admin) user sessions. I have stored user privellege within an ENUM data type, however I'm not sure on how to specify my ENUM values within the PHP. With the following PHP, all users pass through as the first option, including admins (I can tell because the header redirect is the same)

PHP:

```
      else if ($pwdCheck == True){
        session_start();
  $query = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT staff.StaffID, role.Privilege FROM
jobs
INNER JOIN staff ON staff.StaffID = jobs.StaffID
INNER JOIN role ON role.RoleID = jobs.RoleID
WHERE staff.StaffID = "LoginID"');

  $gettier = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
  if($gettier["role.Privilege"] == 0){
    $_SESSION['userID'] = $row['LoginID'];
    header("Location: staffindex.php?login=USERsuccess");
  }
  elseif($gettier["role.Privilege"] == 1){
    $_SESSION['AdminID'] = $row['LoginID'];
    header("Location: staffindex.php?login=ADMINsuccess");
  }

        exit();
      }
```

I know that the issue is in the $gettier["role.Privelege"] part. if I change the contents within the brackets, there is no change (e.g. Admin users pass through with the header USERsuccess instead of ADMINsuccess.) In future, I want to redirect to a different page, but for now I am just redirecting to the same page.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your query output will be:

```
$var['column_name'];
```

**Note:** the array key is *column_name* NOT *table_name.column_name*.

You can clearly see what is being output and then find the correct array key with:

```
error_log(print_r($gettier,true));
```

---

Additional notes:

- You should as far as possible use `===` comparison operators to avoid loose type-mixing. Example: `elseif((int)$gettier['Privilege'] === 1){...`
- Your `session_start()` should be at the top of your script.
- Using URL (`$_GET`) values to define admin (`?login=ADMINsuccess`) are *extremely* prone to compromise. You have sessions in your PHP - use them. Do not use a URL flag for admin authentication as that is absolutely no guarentee that the connecting browser is a valid Admin.

Comment: This is really good! However, when I change to $gettier['Privilege'] there is no luck. Where do I output error_log(print_r($gettier,true)); in order to guess and check?

Comment: @GoGoAllen stick that line after the $gettier var is established and then check your error log file for the data